# Angular 13 application does not load on Cefsharp version 57.0.0.0

Tags: angular, chromium, cefsharp

We use Cefsharp browser version 57.0.0.0 to load our Angular application.
After upgrading the application to Angular 13, it just displays the initial loading page and does not route to the right component. There are no errors in the console.

`navigator.useragent` on console gives the below information.

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
```

Are there any configurations to make Angular 13 with cefsharp 57?

Comment: Hi did you get any solution for this? i am also facing something similar to this

Comment: @NidhinPaul we did not. Behavior on corresponding version of chromium browser was same. So we ended up upgrading to angular 12 only.

Comment: we solved our issue finally....I will post the Stack link asap here. let see this helps you or not when you do ur angular upgrade :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287089/facing-cefsharp-browsersubprocess-has-stopped-working-after-cefsharp-version-upd/75363240#75363240