# Facing Cefsharp.BrowserSubprocess has stopped working after cefsharp version update

Tags: cefsharp

We have a VB windows application project using Cefsharp to display browser screen to display some data.

As part of Angular upgrade we have migrated our current cefsharp version from **75.1.142** to **98.1.21**.

Reason for not updating to latest cefsharp version is when we did the update the application layout is completely affected, font size reduced, controls broken. So we forced to use lower versions.

We used nuget package manager to update the current version.

It is working fine in our local machine, but after deploying the changes to deployment machine we are getting this

```
Cefsharp.BrowserSubprocess has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working...
```

**Please Note**: when we compare the .csproj after the update to **98.1.21** we can see that **Cefsharp.Winform** is now missing in our latest changes under the imported project lists

**Please Note**: currently we are using cefsharp in our 2 projects and **Target Framework** used of these 2 projects are **4.6.2**

This is what we have in our CefSettings initialization method

```
Dim settings As CefSettings = New CefSettings()
settings.remotedebuggingport = findafreetcpport()
settings.cefcommandlineargs.add("disable-gpu", "1")
settings.logfile = ceflogfilename
settings.logseverity = logsiviertity.error
cefsharp.cef.initialize(settings)
```

And my ChromiumBrowser is initialized like this

```
_chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url)
_chromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LedgacyBindingEnabled = True
_chromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.register("bond", new ChromiumWebBrowserEventHandler(Me),True,BindingOptions.DefaultBinder)
```

**Please note**: i haven't provided any **BrowserSubProcesssPath** during my **cefsettings**

And in my both .csproj files I have this

```
 <cefsharpanycpusupport>true</cefsharpanycpusupport>
```

please let me know if you need to know how is my .csproj is configured with cefsharp dll paths.

we also tried different versions but same error is popping out

Any idea why i am facing this problem

Comment: As it works on one machine and not another, what's different between the two? OS? Antivirus? Other software? Hardware? Have you checked the log? Event viewer? Edit your question to add additional details.

Comment: @amaitland do you know why i am facing layout issues in windows form after updating it to latest version. Lower version i am not facing this issue

Comment: @amaitland another thing i noticed is winforms entry is getting disappeared from my csproj import statements after updating it to latest. Is that part of a new version update?

Comment: There were nuget package changes. You've not provided enough information for me to say anything specific. As for your layout and font issues, change the logseverity back to Default and check your log file for errors/warnings. It's impossible to say with so little information. For testing purposes https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample is always kept up to date with the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after many days of nail biting I managed to solve this problem by doing this steps..

1. Updated Cefsharp version with Cefsharp **107.1.121** (latest version was affecting our current windows application layouts. So we forced to stick with this version)
2. Moved **LedgacyBindingEnabled = True** from my **cefsettings** to **ChromiumWebBrowser initialization section** like below

   ```
   _chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url)
   _chromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LedgacyBindingEnabled = True
   _chromeBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.register("bond", new 
   ChromiumWebBrowserEventHandler(Me),True,BindingOptions.DefaultBinder)
   ```
3. Modified cefsettings section by removing the **LedgacyBindingEnabled = True** code
4. Then set this broswersubprocess path to absolute (Important) one like this

   ```
    Dim assemblyPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.reflection.assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)
    If assemblyPath.EndsWith("\") == False Then
       assemblyPath = assemblyPath & "\"
    End If
    Settings.BrowserSubProcesssPath = assemblyPath & 
    "Cefsharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"
   ```

Hope it helps to someone who updates ur Angular version and stuck because of CefSharp version change.